Unable to define a cython function without errors
This is the snippet of the code that I had ran which threw an error when compiled with cython
def __cinit__(self, bitboards = BITBOARDS, board_data = boarddata):
    memcpy(self.bitboards, bitboards, 768)
    self.board_data = board_data

Error:
def __cinit__(self, bitboards = BITBOARDS, board_data = boarddata):
                memcpy(self.bitboards, bitboards, 768)
                         ^
------------------------------------------------------------

brains.pyx:723:25: Cannot convert Python object to 'const void *'

I am unable to understand the reason for this error. All the global variables referred have been initialised. self.bitboard and self.board_data have also been initialised but not assigned
Minimal Reproducible example:
a compiler error is thrown when the following code is compiled (The exact same error as above)
cimport cython
from libc.string cimport memcpy

ctypedef (unsigned long long) U64

cdef U64[2] a = [0, 0]
cdef class test:
    cdef U64[2] b
    def __cinit__(self, param1 = a):
        memcpy(self.b, param1, sizeof(param1))

c = test()

Edit: Upon receiving some suggestions, I ran the following
cimport cython
from libc.string cimport memcpy

ctypedef (unsigned long long) U64

cdef U64[2] a = [0, 0]
cdef class test:
    cdef U64[2] b

    def __cinit__(self):
        pass

    cpdef void set(self, U64[2] param1):
        memcpy(self.b, param1, 128)

c = test()
c.set(a)

The above code threw the following error message:
        cdef U64[2] b

    def __cinit__(self):
        pass

    cpdef void set(self, U64[2] param1):
          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

test.pyx:13:10: Cannot convert 'U64 *' to Python object

Is there any solution to this? Any other way of doing this?

It seems that memcpy expects a const void * as first argument but self.bitboards is not one or cannot be converted to one. That is the reason for the error.

@mkrieger1 I have used memcpy from the standard c library. It is generally used for copying arrays among other thing. Have I used it wrongly here? Or is there any other way in which I should do it?

Looks to me more like bitboards is the problem. That's whatever Python object was passed to the constructor.

@user2357112 I do not think so. In the minimally Reproducible example the same error is thrown. I have defined the variable b as an array of 64 bit integers.

@Randomcoder: In the MRE, you're making the same mistake with param1, which is whatever arbitrary Python object was passed to the constructor. Using a as the default value doesn't change that - I'm pretty sure a will just get converted to a Python object to initialize param1 if you don't pass an explicit value.

As the docs say, "All constructor arguments will be passed as Python objects."

Is there any simple solution to this which can be implemented without forfeiting any performance. I really do require every ounce of performance for the app that I am making. @user2357112 . Thanks for  the help.

Can't you write a cythonized loop like for i, x in enumerate(a): b[i] = x?

@mkrieger1 It still throws the same Error. The error seems to point to the function header itself.

cpdef functions are the worst of all worlds. They have all the restrictions of def functions and all the restrictions of cdef functions. Specifically, all the arguments must be creatable from Python objects. I don't think it's possible to pass U64[2] param1 as a Python object so it isn't an appropriate parameter for a cpdef function
